# quantreg lm.recursive.fit in simple regression without constant

Tags: r, regression

I try to use the function `lm.fit.recursive` in R's `quantreg` package to construct recursive residuals for a simple regression without constant.

Here is a minimal example of an approach that does not work:

```
# some data
n <- 20
z <- rnorm(n)
x <- rnorm(n)
x.mat <- matrix(rnorm(2*n),ncol=2)

lm.fit.recursive(x, z, int=T) # works WITH intercept with one regressor
lm.fit.recursive(x.mat, z, int=F) # works WITHOUT intercept with two regressors
lm.fit.recursive(x, z, int=F) # what I actually want but which returns Error in 1:p : argument of length 0
```

My hunch is that the error is related to the regressor matrix in this case not being a matrix but a vector, which leads R to treat this variable differently.

Is that correct, or am I using the function incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed,

```
> lm.fit.recursive
function (X, y, int = TRUE) 
{
    if (int) 
        X <- cbind(1, X)
    p <- ncol(X)
    n <- nrow(X)
    D <- qr(X[1:p, ])
    ...
}
```

so that `ncol(x)=0` for a vector. Hence,

```
lm.fit.recursive(as.matrix(x,ncol=1), z, int=F)
```

provides a workaround.